# Best way to deal with giant number of combinations python

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a bunch of Twitter data (300 million messages from 450k users) and am trying to unravel a social network through @mentions. My end goal is to have a bunch of pairs where the first item is a pair of @mentions and the second item is the number of users who mention both people. For example: `[(@sam, @kim), 25]`. The order of the @mentions doesn't matter, so `(@sam,@kim)=(@kim,@sam)`.

First I am creating a dictionary where the key is the user id and the value is a set of @mentions

```
for row in data:
    user_id = int(row[1])
    msg = str(unicode(row[0], errors='ignore'))

    if user_id not in userData:
        userData[user_id] = set([ tag.lower() for tag in msg.split() if tag.startswith("@") ])
    else:
        userData[user_id] |= set([ tag.lower() for tag in msg.split() if tag.startswith("@") ])
```

I then loop through the users and create a dictionary where the key is a tuple of @mentions and the values is the number of users who mention both:

```
for user in userData.keys():
    if len(userData[user]) < MENTION_THRESHOLD:
        continue
    for ht in itertools.combinations(userData[user], 2):
        if ht in hashtag_set:
            hashtag_set[ht] += 1
        else:
            hashtag_set[ht] = 1
```

This second part is taking FOREVER to run. Is there a better way to run this and/or a better way to store this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to do all this stuff in-memory as you are now, I would suggest using generators to pipeline your data. Check out this slide deck from PyCon 2008 by David Beazely: http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/GeneratorsUK.pdf

In particular, Part 2 has a number of examples of parsing big data that directly apply to what you want to do. By using generators, you can avoid most of the memory consumption you have now, and I would expect you to see significant performance improvements as a result.